# How to programatically disable an entry for a specific site

Tags: entries, php, multi-site, migration, status

We have a multi-site setup where we would like to disable a bunch of entries on the primary site only. They entries should still be enabled for the second site. I'm working on a migration that looks like this:

```
use Craft;
use craft\db\Migration;
use craft\elements\Entry;
```

```
public function safeUp(): bool
    {
        $success = true;

        $entries = Entry::find()
        ->section('people')
        ->all();

        foreach ($entries as $entry) {
            $entry->setEnabledForSite(false, 1);
            $saved = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
            if ($saved) {
                echo "$entry->title saved";
            } else {
                $success = false;
                echo "$entry->title could not be saved";
            }
        }

        return $success;
    }
```

The changes aren't saving, however. Any thoughts on why?

### Update

Based on Eric Anderson's comment below, the final working code is:

```
public function safeUp(): bool
    {
        $success = true;

        $entries = Entry::find()
        ->section('people')
        ->all();

        foreach ($entries as $entry) {
            $entry->setEnabledForSite([1 => false]);
            $saved = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
            if ($saved) {
                echo "$entry->title saved";
            } else {
                $success = false;
                echo "$entry->title could not be saved";
            }
        }

        return $success;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had success passing an array of `siteId => bool` like so `$entry->enabledForSite = ['1 => false'];` and then saving the element.

Comment: I just figured that out too. That works for me!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure setEnabledForSite takes two arguments if you look at the class reference, it seems to only take one.

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-element.html#method-setenabledforsite

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/v3/src/base/Element.php#L2832-L2842.

I would potentially update your entries criteria to query the entries in the specific site. So something like:

```
$entries = Entry::find()
        ->section('people')
        ->site('siteHandle')
        ->all();
```

Then set in your loop instead:

```
$entry->enabled = false;
```

Comment: Even when selecting a specific site in the query, `$entry->enabled = false` disabled the entry for _all_ sites. I actually figured out why it wasn't saving (unrelated issue) but I'm still not clear on how to set the site for `setEnabledForSite()` In the docs it says "This can also be set to an array of site ID/site-enabled mappings" but I'm not clear on the format.

Comment: @DaltonRooney Ah good to know. thanks for posting an update!